# Concatenating Buffer chunks received from Gridfs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

Only 255kb of data is being sent back, which is the default chunk size in gridfs. In mongolab, however I see that multiple chunks are being stored. So the problem is only with the read code. Here it is-

Retrive from gridfs and send response code-

```
app.get('/download/:fileid', function(req, res) {
    var buffer = [];
    var id = req.params.fileid;
    var base64string;
    var readStream = gfs.createReadStream({_id: id});
    readStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
     buffer.push(chunk);
    });
    readStream.on('end', function() {
      base64string = Buffer(buffer.concat()[0]).toString('base64');
      fs.writeFile("base64.txt", base64string);
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.write(JSON.stringify({body : base64string}));
      res.end();
    });
});
```

[Edit]- Further analysis suggests that I am getting all the chunks. So the problem is in concatenation-

```
base64string = Buffer(buffer.concat()[0]).toString('base64');
```

[Edit]- Buffer.concat() does not work. How do I create a single buffer out of these three buffers?

```
[ <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 01 00 60 00 60 00 00 ff e1 0f 07 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00
 08 00 06 01 32 00 02 00 00 00 14 00 00 ... >,
  <Buffer a1 b1 42 92 56 81 43 43 5e b8 46 61 0f 96 09 c1 c4 e8 96 2b 75 52 54 21 2a 7d 46 ba c6 66 80 01 95 3c 3d a7 16
 31 ed d9 56 b5 2b 91 5e 07 14 cb 2f ee ... >,
  <Buffer a6 b6 92 5a 4f 1a da c9 e8 55 97 8e d1 da 4a b3 88 26 2f e5 2c 23 2a 54 10 59 1b 9e eb 35 e8 92 cc 2e da 8b 16
 91 d3 e2 91 93 99 62 e0 8e a3 80 56 aa ... >,
  <Buffer 71 e6 83 65 5e b0 f1 5f 61 a6 21 a3 68 83 be 72 0b 7a 7d 47 d6 d3 69 ee 59 37 92 1a de 06 8a 22 2a 3a a0 a3 1f
 1a 0e 7e ec 67 3b 8f e9 c5 87 6b 41 5b ... > ]
```

[EDIT] Piping the readstream into response as per neils recommendation. However I get a syntax error on client side. [Unexpected Token]

RESPONSE CODE-

```
app.get('/download/:fileid', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.fileid;
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    gfs.createReadStream({_id: id}).pipe(res); });
```

CLIENT CODE-

```
 download() {
    this._http.get('http://localhost:9000/download/' + this._fileid)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(
       data => {
       console.log(data);
       //this.image = data.body;
      },
      err => console.log('Error is..:' + err)
      );;
  }
```

Comment: Why are you sending this as "base64"? Surely the client cannot be dependent on receiving a JSON encoded string only? What is the client? A browser? If so then just serve each "image link" independently and let the browser use it's natural cache. At any rate, the "client" probably "should" be receiving binary data as opposed to wrapping in a stringified package. I see very few valid use cases for packaging "image data" in such a way.

Comment: Yes my client is a browser. The JSON format natively doesn't support binary data. However could  you rtell me how, I can concatenate the binary buffers, surely I would need to do that, in either scenario. Also are you recommending binary over base64 because they take about 30% more space than binary. I do not have an image link as I am not using the filesystem rather storing this data in gridfs, if i understood you correctly

Comment: So don't send as JSON. Here's the case. Say you are packaging 10 images in your JSON response. Whilst you "could" do that and the browser makes **one** request, it needs to do so **every** time you request that content. On the other hand if you create API endpoints like `/image/:id`, then whilst it would be **10 requests**, these are likely done in parallel ( speedy ) as well as any such content will be "cached". This means any subsequent call for the same content leaves the server alone and uses the "cached" content. So **speedier**.

Comment: That's the main case, as well as "yes of course" any "base64" encoding natually means even more "bandwidth" is being consumed. There are cases for an "inline base64" image content, such as a "pallete" of images that are commonly used. But serving content sourced in a database is **not** a good use case for doing so. Use individual endpoints with binary data instead.

Comment: Actually I am not packaging several images in one request. Gridfs stores one images into multiple chunks of 255kb each. So I need to concatenate all the chunks and then send the response back for a single image. That is the central problem and hence the need to concatenate the buffers. Coming back to not using JSON, how would I send binary data back?

Comment: It's just an "example" case. Certainly for one image the case is even stronger. You are approaching this in the **wrong way**. Just let the client "naturally" request a standard resource as an "image" from the API. It's then a simple matter of "piping" the GridFS stream to the response. It's going to save you wasting time on this implementation and deliver a better result to do so.

Comment: gfs.createReadStream({_id: id}).pipe(res) ?

Comment: Yep. You might want to set the `Content-Type` on `res` for good measure first. But that's the general idea.

Comment: Hey Neil, the response is going fine, however I am getting a synntax error on client side. Please see edit in the post

Comment: You're "still" trying to use this as an XHR. Just set the `src` on a regular image tag and let the browser do the rest.

Comment: Hey Neil, I am unable to extract the data out of the response. I am only aware of the .map(res => res.Json()). Can you please help me out with an answer or point me to a documentation